# Make a method to run only for sometime

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there anyway that i can come out of a method no matter that method is completely executed or not. I need it to be ran only for like 4 sec. Is there anyway to do this?.

EDITED:

If i am trying to check the reachability of a host which takes too much time on checking and mean while i really want the feedback from reachability to go further what can i do on this. 
I would like to cancel the reachability check if it takes more that 4 secs and i want to continue my app to work on offline mode. I don't really want my user to wait for sometime until i get the feedback from Reachabiltiy.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirements.. I fear it is too generic.. and it may be closed!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. See my [revised answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851316/1271826) which outlines how you'd use a combination of notifications and timers to achieve the desired UX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've updated your question to clarify that you're dealing with Reachability. What I might suggest is the following:

1. Add your controller as an observer of the `kReachabilityChangedNotification` as shown in [Apple's Reachability code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).
2. Create your `Reachability` object and start the notifier:

   ```
   self.hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
   [self.hostReach startNotifier];
   ```
3. Create your 4 second `NSTimer`.
4. Present the UI that indicates that you're trying to establish the connection with your server. For example, at a minimum, you'd want some view in front of your UI that prevents user interaction with your app, and you might want a `UIActivityViewIndicator` that lets the user know the app is busy doing something.
5. Wait for either your timer to go off or for the `Reachability` notification to fire.
6. Which ever does, you can then stop the Reachability notifier, remove your UI that you presented in step 4, and proceed, either offline or online, as appropriate. Obviously, if you got the Reachability notifier before your timer, you'd probably want to `invalidate` your four second timer, too.

---

Original answer:

You generally have to program something like this yourself, and it depends upon what your method does. For example, this is quite easy to do with a `NSURLConnection` (you could set up a timer that does a `cancel` of the connection) or if you have some method with a `for` loop in which you could check for time elapsed by looking at `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` versus some earlier value. I depends entirely upon what your method is doing.

An alternative is to dispatch this to some background thread, and that way, you might not care as much about the timing of the method.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // do some time consuming process

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // all UI updates should be dispatched back to the main queue
    });
});
```

Again, it depends entirely upon what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You have to arrange for this yourself. In your long-running method, periodically check a "cancelled" flag:

```
while (![context isCancelled] || workIsFinished) {
  [self nextPartOfTimeConsumingWork];
}
```

If you find that this flag has been set, stop the work. You can then set this flag in some external code that's running your timer.

If you use `NSThread` or `NSOperationQueue` for concurrency, you'll get `-cancel` and `-isCancelled` built into them which do exactly as described here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer in the method...

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 4.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(myMethod:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
```

So after 4 seconds, you can call a method to handle offline mode.

In the method you want ot end after 4s, you check if timer invalidate using

```
[NSTimer isValid]
```